# Is there a way to "watch" a question posted by someone else? Be alerted to changes, comments and answers?

Tags: feature-request

Quite regularly I come across really good questions, that I'd like to know the answer to myself, but there doesn't seem to be a way to achieve this within the askubuntu functionality.

Am I missing a trick?
Does anyone else think this would be a useful feature (assuming it's not already there)?

**Does the suggested "Favourite" star enable alerts for the following?**:

- Question updates
- Comments
- New Answers
- Answer updates

Comment: I have just seen your edit to this, do you not accept the duplicate? AFAIK the favourite button will only notify you about new answers on questions, not comments or edits or anything else. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work

Comment: It's kind of similar, but has no alerting functionality which, if questions that have been favourited could send alerts out in the same way that your own questions/answers/comments do rather than having to manage them separately and actually look into each one to search for changes.

Comment: I couldn't find anything to extend the functionality of the favourites. For now I voted to reopen this based on the edit.

Comment: Just reading the blog and it says "Next month we will release our Follow Questions capability (something that has been discussed by the community for years). This feature will allow users to “follow” or “unfollow” questions. You’ll be notified on new activity for questions you follow and have the ability to silence questions you no longer want to be notified about to reduce the noise you receive in your inbox." This might be exactly what you requested here. https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/25/sharing-our-first-quarter-2020-community-roadmap/

Comment: Following questions is now a thing, I was going to answer this but I will just leave a link because it is still closed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network

Comment: @MarkKirby I've voted to reopen the question. IMHO it deserves a separate answer.